# java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed when running Ammonite

Tags: windows, scala, ammonite

I have installed scala 3.2.2, which includes ammonite, coursier, scala repl. When trying to run ammonite I receive the following error:

```
C:\Users\myuser>amm
Loading...
Welcome to the Ammonite Repl 3.0.0-M0-19-62705f47 (Scala 3.2.2 Java 11.0.15)

@ var me = "victor"

java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: asTerm called on not-a-Term val <none>
  scala.runtime.Scala3RunTime$.assertFailed(Scala3RunTime.scala:8)
  dotty.tools.dotc.core.Symbols$Symbol.asTerm(Symbols.scala:169)
  dotty.tools.dotc.core.Definitions.ObjectClass(Definitions.scala:337)
  dotty.tools.dotc.core.Definitions.ObjectType(Definitions.scala:341)
  dotty.tools.dotc.core.Definitions.AnyRefAlias(Definitions.scala:440)
  dotty.tools.dotc.core.Definitions.syntheticScalaClasses(Definitions.scala:1959)
  dotty.tools.dotc.core.Definitions.syntheticCoreClasses(Definitions.scala:1970)
  dotty.tools.dotc.core.Definitions.init(Definitions.scala:1987)
  dotty.tools.dotc.core.Contexts$ContextBase.initialize(Contexts.scala:868)
  ammonite.compiler.Compiler.initialCtx(Compiler.scala:145)
  ammonite.compiler.Compiler.preprocessor(Compiler.scala:313)
  ammonite.compiler.CompilerLifecycleManager.preprocess(CompilerLifecycleManager.scala:67)
  ammonite.interp.Interpreter.$anonfun$processLine$4(Interpreter.scala:254)
  ammonite.util.Res$Success.flatMap(Res.scala:62)
  ammonite.interp.Interpreter.$anonfun$processLine$2(Interpreter.scala:247)
  ammonite.util.Catching.flatMap(Res.scala:115)
  ammonite.interp.Interpreter.processLine(Interpreter.scala:246)
  ammonite.repl.Repl.$anonfun$action$8(Repl.scala:202)
  ammonite.util.Res$Success.flatMap(Res.scala:62)
  ammonite.repl.Repl.$anonfun$action$4(Repl.scala:189)
  ammonite.repl.Scoped.$anonfun$flatMap$1(Signaller.scala:45)
  ammonite.repl.Signaller.apply(Signaller.scala:28)
  ammonite.repl.Scoped.flatMap(Signaller.scala:45)
  ammonite.repl.Scoped.flatMap$(Signaller.scala:45)
  ammonite.repl.Signaller.flatMap(Signaller.scala:16)
  ammonite.repl.Repl.$anonfun$action$2(Repl.scala:181)
  ammonite.util.Catching.flatMap(Res.scala:115)
  ammonite.repl.Repl.action(Repl.scala:173)
  ammonite.repl.Repl.loop$1(Repl.scala:215)
  ammonite.repl.Repl.run(Repl.scala:230)
  ammonite.Main.run(Main.scala:245)
  ammonite.MainRunner.$anonfun$runRepl$1(MainRunner.scala:72)
  ammonite.MainRunner.watchLoop(MainRunner.scala:53)
  ammonite.MainRunner.runRepl(MainRunner.scala:72)
  ammonite.AmmoniteMain$.main0(AmmoniteMain.scala:99)
  ammonite.AmmoniteMain$.main(AmmoniteMain.scala:38)
  ammonite.AmmoniteMain.main(AmmoniteMain.scala)
  jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
  coursier.bootstrap.launcher.a.a(Unknown Source)
  coursier.bootstrap.launcher.Launcher.main(Unknown Source)
```

So far I have rerun the installation file but (`cs-x86_64-pc-win32.exe`) but the error persists. I am on Windows 10 Enterprise. Has anyone faced the same issue?